# Implement form with check box and text area in install4j

Tags: install4j

I wants to add a form in installation process which includes a checkbox and two text boxes. **Initially** check box has to be in enable state and text boxes has to be in **disable state**. When ever we **check on check box** the text **boxes has to be in enable state** and vice versa.

Please give a information about how to create this form and how implement the enable and disable features by using the install4j options.

Thanks and regards,
Jagadeesh Musham.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set that up in the install4j IDE without any code: The configuration of the a check box form component has a "Coupled form components" tab that shows all other form components. Select your text fields in that list then they will only be enabled if the check box is selected.

Comment: Please accept my answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work